# JasperReports xlsx export error - Unreadable content - why?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, xls, xlsx

receive an "Unreadable Content" error from Excel whenever the results of my crosstab report is > 702 columns (column ZZ).   When less than this number of columns - no error.  Is there a limit?  XLSX should handle 16,000+ columns.

We are using JasperReports v4.0.1 and POI 3.6.  I have attempted and recreated this same issue using JasperReports v4.7 and POI 3.7.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Export Code:

```
JRXlsxExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();

File fileP = new File(_workdir + report_name + ".jrprint");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint)
JRLoader.loadObject(fileP);

xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);

xlsExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
xlsExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, _outputName);
System.out.println("Exporting Excel Report to " + _outputName);
xlsExporter.exportReport();
System.out.println("Export Complete.");
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors?  Is the resulting file actually generated?

Comment: Also, you might want to increase the log level for Jasper to see if POI or Jasper itself is throwing any errors.

Comment: No errors during the report generation or export.  Only when trying to open the Excel file itself.  The file is created, but it gives an Unreadable Content error and has little to no actual data in it.

Comment: I should add the we are writing the output to a file and then emailing the file to the requester.  This is not being displayed in a browser.

Comment: Matt, simplify what you are trying to accomplish. (1) Get the export to XLSX first working in iReport. (2) Get one of the simple examples from the JasperReports tutorial working. (3) Add complexity until you get the empty/corrupt Excel file. (4) See if you can use CSV format instead -- most bosses think "Excel" when they should think "Spreadsheet"; CSV is generally superior to XSLX for output that does not need formatting.

Comment: @DaveJarvis - I have been able to get the XLSX working.  It works flawlessly until the data reported on expands to use more than 702 columns (ZZ).

Comment: Try using CSV and see if you still have the same column restriction. You should be able to get up to 16,384 columns.

Comment: @DaveJarvis - CSV format produces a file with all the data, no errors.  However, the formatting (borders, colors, etc) are no longer included.  We would prefer to use the xlsx format if we could understand how to fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
JRXlsxExporter jrXlsxExporter=new JRXlsxExporter();
jrXlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
jrXlsxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "export.xlsx");
jrXlsxExporter.exportReport();
```